# iOS app that uses Alexa Voice Service (AVS)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, alexa-voice-service

A couple of questions about the use of Alexa Voice Services within an enterprise app.

Can anyone confirm that the Alexa Voice Service API can actually be used within an iOS app? I'm seeing old projects on GitHub that won't compile in XCode 8, and Amazon has nothing in the way of iOS demo app code for version 2 of the service.

Also, can someone explain if the app needs to include a login-with-Amazon button? I want to create an enterprise app which uses a specific Alexa skill I've written (runs find on the Amazon Echo hardware device) but which the users of the app can simply tap a button to converse with the skill. I don't want to require them to have to log into Amazon (many of them won't have Amazon accounts) or need to verbally "connect" to the skill.

Thanks

Comment: Is your custom skills working in AVS inside iOS app? I have integrated Alexa voice service in iOS app for my custom Skills, it is not working inside app. But my skill is working in Alexa echo dot. How to resolve this issue. I want to make my skills to access inside iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has an interest in this, I was told in an amazon forum that the Alexa service isn't set up to do this, it's essentially provided to enable a conduit to amazon shopping. Big dissapointment.