# Can we use Alexa skill from custom iOS app?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, avs

Can I use Alexa skill from my iOS application (just like we do it from the Echo dot etc)?

I checked a few [old links](https://github.com/chintan1891/iOS-Alexa) which are working as follows, and I think it can be done using AVS:

1. record the message
2. upload it and get Alexa's response
3. Play it using some player

For that, it needs token (which can be obtained if a user logs in).
I checked a few SO links ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434573/ios-app-that-uses-alexa-voice-service-avs), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271548/avs-with-alexa-skills)) as well but didn't get the answer.

**Is there any SDK or API to do it?** I didn't get enough info from AWS documentation.

Is it even possible? How to use AVS in my iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to explore [AWS LEX](https://aws.amazon.com/lex/). It is the same service that powers Alexa. It allows you to create conversational bots, that can consume voice or text input and can give back voice or text output. You can integrate lex in any application whether it is mobile, web or voice application.

Here is a useful link that you can follow to understand how you can utilize LEX for your iOS app.

[Deploying an Amazon Lex Bot in Mobile Applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/example2.html)